# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in my net.MVC application

Tags: c#, oracle, entity

I have these two methods (the first is the one that throws the error):

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetRegions()
        {
            return this.manager.GetRegions().ToList().Select(c => 
            new SelectListItem { Value = (c.ID).ToString(), Text = c.DES }).ToList();
        }

public IQueryable<VIEW> GetRegions()
        {
            return    from p in this.context.Read()
                      group p by new { p.ID }
                      into mygroup
                      select mygroup.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

This is excpetion:
"Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 does not support APPLY"

**UPDATE**
I have tried this and it gives no errors but obviously I have duplicate data (SelectMany), the Distinct does not work

```
((this.context.Read().GroupBy(item => item.ID)                          
                     .ToArray())
                     .SelectMany(x=>x.Distinct()))
.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Any chance to upgrade to Oracle 12? [See here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/new-dotnet-features.html) "LINQ: SQL APPLY keyword support for lateral views"

Comment: I cannot change the version